# Rails Ajax: .js.erb rendered as text, not executed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to

I'm using jquery-rails gem with `javascript_include_tag :defaults`. Hence the page has header:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1312437063" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1312437070" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1311268601" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/> 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="KdgrBxF726xfPP3qbNOHd/0TG9c7lVCoZDXPnadFOzI="/>
```

Ajax request comes from the view with the line:

```
<%= link_to 'Run', :controller => "config_panel", :action => "full_run", :remote => true, :format => :js %>
```

It's rendered as:

```
<a href="/config_panel/full_run.js?remote=true">Run</a>
```

Response defined in controller:

```
def full_run
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :text => "alert();"}
    format.xml
  end
end
```

When link clicked, the server logs:

```
Started GET "/config_panel/full_run.js?remote=true"
Processing by ConfigPanelController#full_run as JS
Parameters: {"remote"=>"true"}
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And browser shows plain text:

```
alert();
```

The HTML header has `status: 200` and `content-type: text/javascript`. And Chrome JavaScript console shows no error.

I tried the following workaround:

- include rails.js --- failed
- change `link_to` to `<div onclick="$.ajax(...)">` --- worked

I'm very confused by the behavior of `:remote =>` true in `link_to`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Run', { :controller => "config_panel", :action => "full_run" }, :remote => true %>
```

if you used route helpers, passing it as a hash wouldn't be necessary

[link_to reference](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper%3alink_to)